# How to use an autocomplete edit control in an MFC Ribbon Application

Tags: c++, autocomplete, mfc, ribbon, autocompletebox

I need to develop a search module for an mfc ribbon application using C++. I have used auto complete feature in C#.NET but never worked on any mfc ribbon application. I want auto complete search with an icon image as prefix of each suggestion, just like Facebook search. I have also consulted [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/489189/Group-Combo-Box) article, but that uses CComboBox, I need to use CMFCRibbonCombobox in my program because I tried with CCombobox but that was causing problems. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create your own `CMFCRibbonComboBox` derived class, that will be pretty much a copy of the `CMFCRibbonFontCombBox` without the fonts.
to check how you draw the images you can check the `CMFCRibbonFontComboBox::OnDrawDropListItem` implementation.

Then I think that you will have to dynamicaly add it to the ribbon.

Comment: This gets to be a real pain if you're using the ribbon designer as your code won't actually have any CMFCRibbonComboBox items that can be replaced with the derived class.  The approach I took was to rewrite one of the base classes as per the answer linked below.  Blatant hack, but works better.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39728045/how-to-get-notification-for-keydown-for-cmfcribboncombobox