# How to get notification for keydown for CMFCRibbonComboBox?

Tags: mfc, cmfcribbonpanel

I  have CMFCRibbonComboBox on ribonbar and I want when that user press on a key open droplist and select Item acurding to chars that press by user.

For this purpose I want to get notification for keydown.

How can I to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to re-invent standard combo box functionality?

Comment: I will happy to any solution I can't to find how to it with standard way can you please help to me?

Comment: @linspectable because the MFC ribbon combo box lacks much of the basic very important functionality of the normal MFC and Windows combo box such as searching.  As a UI MFC ribbon has some pretty glaring omissions.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a very similar question on MSDN [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a82f1662-a123-4439-a9d4-cee27f19618e/automatically-searching-drop-down-lists-in-mfc-ribbon-combobox-controls?forum=vcgeneral#5ba6650e-53da-434f-82ca-e3a8837b1769) and eventually solved it myself with the following hack;

Save a local copy of **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\afxribbonedit.cpp** to your project

In `BOOL CMFCRibbonRichEditCtrl::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)` replace this

```
    case VK_DOWN:
        if (m_edit.m_bHasDropDownList && !m_edit.IsDroppedDown())
        {
            m_edit.DropDownList();
            return TRUE;
        }
```

with this

```
case VK_DOWN:
        if (m_edit.m_bHasDropDownList && !m_edit.IsDroppedDown())
        {
            m_edit.DropDownList();
            CMFCRibbonBaseElement* pRibbonBaseElement = m_edit.GetDroppedDown();
            if (pRibbonBaseElement && (pRibbonBaseElement->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCRibbonComboBox))))
            {
                CString str;
                GetWindowText(str);
                CMFCRibbonComboBox *pCombo = (CMFCRibbonComboBox*)pRibbonBaseElement;
                int ItemNo = -1;
                for (int i = 0; i < pCombo->GetCount(); i++)
                {
                    CString ItemText = pCombo->GetItem(i);
                    if (ItemText.Left(str.GetLength()).CompareNoCase(str) == 0)
                    {
                        ItemNo = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (ItemNo != -1)
                {
                    pCombo->OnSelectItem(ItemNo);
                    // Draw and redraw dropdown for selection to show
                    m_edit.DropDownList();
                    m_edit.DropDownList();
                }
            }
            return TRUE;
        }
```

For drop lists (as opposed to drop downs) you can similarly hand WM_CHAR to do a first letter search based on the next item after the current position.  Note that the above hack would need to be checked against any future updates to the ribbon library and should be dumped once it has been properly implemented in the library.